# NFTs and transfer fees

Tags: ethereum

I have read in various places that NFTs can be created which pay a transaction fee payable to minter of the NFT when it is transferred between owners.

But I don't see in the ERC 721 spec where that property (the amount paid to the creator on transfer of the token) is defined and "written" into the token.  I wonder whether fees payable to creators on each sale of a NFT  an off chain transaction by the platform on which the NFTs are bought and sold, rather than embodied feature of the NFT enforced by the blockchain transfer mechanism?  If it is embodied, where is it specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) standard only defines an **interface**. So the actual implementation of the interface or its extension is up to each contract developer.

Token minting or transfer rules are features that you can simply define on your own and in whichever way suits your needs. You can have

- a fee that is deducted on each transfer going to the creator
- an admin address that is allowed to define the price and anyone who pays can mint without any more fees
- anyone freely minting and transfering new NFTs
- only authorized addresses allowed to mint and transfer the tokens (and the authorization and possible payment are done off-chain)
- no minting and transfers at all
- etc...

So in short, the ERC-721 doesn't define any way how to "correctly" mint or transfer new tokens and you're free to implement it however you need.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wondering how difficult it might be for a purchaser of an NFT on say, niftygateway.com or opensea to figure out what "taxes" are built into the NFT versus those that are just enforced by the transaction platform.  I was surprised as a newbie to see 15% of the sale proceeds on Niftygateway going to a combination of transaction fees (5%) and artist royalty (10%) and wondering if I pulled the NFT from niftygateway marketplace, and sold it elsewhere would those charges deducted when the I sold the NFT.

Comment: @GGizmos Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the NFT market space, so this is going to be just an educated guess. I haven't found any transfer fees in [this](https://niftygateway.com/marketplace?collection=0xe9be55ffedb6c2a2f3f8eac31c60d7f122f79958) random token [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xe9be55ffedb6c2a2f3f8eac31c60d7f122f79958) so it seems like the market is acting as a middle man: 1) The buyer sends the money to the market. 2) The market then deducts their fee and buys the token from the seller. 3) And finally sends the token to the buyer and part of the fee to the seller.

Comment: Thanks.  @PetrHejda When u have chance, check your LinkedIn.  Sent you a private message there.